# Laravel - how to configure css and js files

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-blade, webpack-dev-server

I have a project with laravel and I have configured the following file for webpack, but then in my template I use a file "head.blade.php" where I load all the vendors, I use jquery, boostrap, moment ... etc

When I upload this and pass a performance test on google page speed or other services it tells me that I have more than 20 JS that compress them, and I don't know how to do it.

**File webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.scripts([
    'resources/js/app.js',
    'resources/js/bootstrap.js'
], 'public/js/app.js').extract([
], 'public/js/vendors.js').version();

mix.scripts([
    'resources/js/cars.js',
], 'public/js/cars.js').extract([
], 'public/js/vendors.js').version();

mix.scripts([
    'resources/js/customers.js',
], 'public/js/customers.js').extract([
], 'public/js/vendors.js').version();

mix.js('resources/js/bootstrap-table-es-ES.js', 'public/js');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

**Head.blade.php**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

<meta content="" name="descriptison">
<meta content="" name="keywords">


<!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
<link href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css')  }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css')  }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/remixicon/remixicon.css')  }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css')  }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Template Main CSS File -->
<link href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.css')  }}" rel="stylesheet">

{{--JQUERY--}}
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js') }}"></script>

{{--BOOTSTRAP-TABLES--}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/boostrap-tables/bootstrap-table.min.css')  }}">
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/boostrap-tables/bootstrap-table.min.js')  }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/boostrap-tables/bootstrap-table-es-ES.min.js')  }}"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/popper/popper.min.js')  }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')  }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/bootstrap-table-es-ES.js') }}"></script>


<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/moment/moment.min.js') }}"></script>

<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Thanxs,

Comment: Can you please explain more details so easy to understood?

Comment: I have a project in laravel, which makes use of many third-party libraries, such as boostrap, jquery, etc ... And the problem I have is that if I do a "speed test" they penalize the code of my website because they tell me that I am trying to load 20 different JS files. They recommend that you join these files.